# UIPageViewController dog-ear link in Maps

Tags: ios, ipad, animation, effect, uipageviewcontroller

I am wondering, when using a page with *UIPageViewController*, on how to add a dog-ear, just like in the iPad Maps Application. I need it to clarify, that there are multiple pages that can be turned.

Here is a screenshot of the Maps Application, with a finger pointing to the dog-ear: http://www.patentlyapple.com/.a/6a0120a5580826970c0120a81c19f7970b-800wi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The built-in Maps application probably uses a private API involving a CoreImage filter to do the page curl.  This is how the iBooks app works (or worked before `UIPageViewController` was invented).

There are some open-source attempts to implement a similar page-curl effect.  You might check them out.  Here's one: http://api.mutado.com/mobile/paperstack/